# MobileFirst build with gradle, get [android/init] timeout, works fine if built with ant

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Developer server version is
`mfp -v: 7.1.0.00.20160206-1603`
Production server version is
`wladm -version 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630`
Project is `mfp cordova` type.

Building for developer server.
App built with Ant works.
App built with Gradle works.

Building for production server.
App built in release/debug with Ant - works fine.
App built in release/debug with Gradle, gets [...android/init] timeout or 500.

Signing is the same.
Configuration is the same.
wlapp is properly deployed to production and developer server.
On device app looks fine. Everything is ok, but cannot connect to WL server.

Looks like something is wrong with app authenticity.
But Ant signed-release works. Gradle signed-release/debug fails to connect.
Same project, same settings. Whats wrong. Have you seen this?

EDIT
Looking at logcat logs, found this error
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/.../base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/.../lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libauthjni.so"`
But when I just change address (wlclient.properties) to local Dev server - everything is ok. No error.

Comment: Are you actually using authenticity? You did not mention this.

Comment: I haven't defined any security test in application-descriptor.xml. So default mobile security test kicks in. And it has app authenticity check enabled.

Comment: Then you need to disable it. Or properly configure the app for authenticity.

Comment: But this config works properly with Ant. Does build with Ant differ from build with Gradle.

Comment: added production server version `wladm -version  7.1.0.00.20150807-0630` Maybe builds are incompatible with old production server version. But it works with Ant...

Answer (score 0):

Cordova applications created with the CLI are based on Cordova 3.7.
Cordova 3.7 does not support a Gradle-based project structure.